# How do I prove that 0 is the only eigenvalue for this?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $N : V → V$ be a linear transformation such that $N^k$ is the zero transformation for some
positive integer $k$. How do I prove that the only eigenvalue of $N$ is $0$?

Answer (score 3):

Use induction to show that, if $Nv=\lambda v$, then $N^kv=\lambda^kv$

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $N$. Then, there is a non-zero vector $v\in V$ such that $N(v)=\lambda v$. Applying $N$ repeatedly $k-1$ times to both sides of this equality, it follows, due to linearity, that $0=N^{k}(v)=\lambda^{k}v$. Since $v$ is non-zero, it must be that $\lambda =0$. Hence, if $N$ has an eigenvalue, it must be $0$.

To see that $0$ is indeed an eigenvalue of $N$, take any non-zero vector $v \in V$ such that $w:=N^{k-1}(v)\not= 0$ (we can always find such a $v$ if we assume $k$ is the smallest positive integer with the given property). Then, $N(w)=N^{k}(v)=0=0\cdot w$, so that $0$ is an eigenvalue of $N$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue if and only if $\lambda$ is a root of the minimal polynomial, $m_{N}(x)$. Since $N^{k} = 0$, $N$ satisfies $f(x) = x^{k}$. Hence, by definition of minimal polynomial, $m_{N}(x)$ must divide $f(x)$. Hence, $m_{N}(x) = x^{d}.$